# Jquery - Regex not working when used with name replace - when passed within variable

Tags: jquery, regex

Please see if you can explain this code below

```
//The code below does not work
var regEx = "/myList\\[[0-9]\\]/gi";
this.name =this.name.replace(regEx , function (x) {
  return 'myList[' + index + ']';
});

//The code below Works
this.name = this.name.replace(/myList\[[0-9]\]/gi, function (x) {
  return 'myList[' + index + ']';
});
```

The regex when declared as a variable does not work

Comment: ignore index. It gets passed in. The code that works  substitutes with passed in index

Comment: You should probably have a read of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Remove the quotes where you are assigning the `regEx` variable and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The first code doesn't work because it is String, not regex, so need to use RegExp object to work

```
//Had to use RegExp to make it work 
var name = "x.y.myList[0].test";
var regEx2 = new RegExp("myList\\[[0-9]\\]", "gi");
alert(name.replace(regEx2 , function (x) { return 'myList[' + 1 + ']'}));
```

The second code works because it is regex